# $SO(3)$ via the tensor product representation of $SU(2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, tensor-products

Consider the tensor product representation of $SU(2)$ on the space $V_2 \otimes V_2$. Let the basis of $V_2$ be $\{e_1, e_2\}$. The representation breaks into two irreducible ones, one of which is supported by the symmetric subspace, with basis $\{e_1 \otimes e_1, (e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1 )/\sqrt{2}, e_2 \otimes e_2\}$. For an element

$$ \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
   z_1  & -\bar{z_2} \\
    z_2 & \bar{z_1} \\
  \end{array}
\right)  $$

in SU(2),  its representation in the symmetric subspace is

$$ \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   z_1^2 & -\sqrt{2} \bar{z_2} z_1 &  \bar{z_2}^2 \\
    \sqrt{2}z_1 z_2 & z_1 \bar{z_1} - z_2 \bar{z_2} &  -\sqrt{2} \bar{z_1} \bar{z_2} \\
    z_2^2 & \sqrt{2} \bar{z_1} z_2 & \bar{z_1}^2 \\
  \end{array}
\right) $$

It is complex. I expect that it is isomorphic to the $SO(3)$ group. How to show this?